# Не получается подключиться к БД в psycorg2 python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Начал изучать psycopg2, чтобы решить с помощью неё одну свою задачу - импортировать csv в sql. С sqlite3 уже познакомился немного, но насколько понял, в нем нет возможности импорта из csv, аналогичной psycorg2 (https://www.dataquest.io/blog/loading-data-into-postgres/). В остальном все более-менее аналогично. Начал подключаться к БД как пишут во всех инструкциях и сразу же вылезает непонятная ошибка. Подскажите пожалуйста, что это может быть и как исправить? PostgreSQL установлен, действую по инструкции...

```
# Подключаемся к БД
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", database="employees", user="postgres", password='postgres')

# Return mistake, don't know what's going on. Everything similar to tutorials, and dont'work.
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/hello_psycopg2/hello_psycopg2.py", line 4, in <module>
#     conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", database="employees", user="postgres", password='postgres')
#   File "C:\Users\home\PycharmProjects\hello_psycopg2\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
#     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
# psycopg2.OperationalError
```

Comment: Обычно после psycopg2.OperationalError идёт более подробное описание ошибки...

Comment: @MaxU Как пишут здесь: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/417 при неанглийской локали тест ошибки может не отдаваться.

Comment: @strawdog, спасибо за информацию, не знал о таком жирном баге.

Answer (score 0):

вместо database (устарело) пишите dbname, должно все заработать.
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect

Comment: Пробовал, всплывает та же самая ошибка.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/hello_psycopg2/hello_psycopg2.py", line 4, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", dbname="employees", user="postgres", password='postgres')
  File "C:\Users\home\PycharmProjects\hello_psycopg2\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

Comment: @user330377 что написано после psycopg2.OperationalError?

Comment: @Ghostic2005 Ничего. Я привел весь текст ошибки.

Comment: @user330377 а если заключить connect в try - except и в исключении сделать traceback.print_exc() - что будет в выводе?

Comment: Только сейчас руки дошли. Все равно выдает ошибку. During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/home/Documents/PycharmProjects/find_torrent_file/find_torrent_file.py", line 15, in <module>
    traceback.print_exc()
NameError: name 'traceback' is not defined

Comment: @user330377 Ну надо сделать import traceback

Comment: @Ghostic2005 сделал, вот результат: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/psycopg2/psycogp2.py", line 6, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", database="employees", user="postgres", password='postgres')
  File "C:\Users\home\PycharmProjects\psycopg2\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

Answer (score 0):

```py
import psycopg2

db = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=test user=test_user password=GUm9xMB port=5432")
```

В функцию передаются данные для соединения в качестве строки, а не как аргументы функции

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка вероятнее всего связана с тем, что вы указываете в параметре `dbname` название самого сервера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. картинку:

1. Название сервера
2. Название базы данных

Соответственно учитывая всё выше сказанное код для создания подключения будет выглядеть следующим образом (за пример взята моя база данных имя может отличаться):

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", dbname="postgres", user="postgres", password='postgres')
```